# How to get a coredump from `abrt`

Tags: linux, fedora, abrt

I'm running Fedora 23, and just recently discovered that `abrt` handles the coredumps from my crashed application, and places all kind of stuff in `/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-date-pid`. Is there a command to fetch a coredump from `abrt`, without manually copying it from the indicated folder? Or could I have `abrt` feed the coredump to gdb, and also load the binary?

I would prefer not to change `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`.

I'm thinking somehting along the lines of:

```
$ cc -g -o foo main.c
$ ./foo
segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ abrt-magic d55ba08dd0535a223d4a7...
(gdb) # time to do post mortem debugging...
```

Where of course `abrt-magic` would be replaced with some command.

If there is no such command, is there some other aproach? I've read that `systemd` has some coredump util, but I couldn't find it in my distro.

I originally posted this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35893299/491426), but perhaps the question is better suited here.

Comment: The location of coredumps handled by `abrt` is specified in `/etc/abrt/abrt.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@meuh answered this on Stackoverflow, and this was pretty much the answer I was looking for.

You can get an "old-fashioned" core dump in the usual current directory of the process, if the `ulimit -c` value allows it, by setting

```
MakeCompatCore = yes
```

in config file `/etc/abrt/plugins/CCpp.conf`.